# What is the maximum size of a DataTable I can load into memory in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datatable

What is the maximum size of a DataTable I can load into memory in .Net?

Is there an artificial limitation, or it is only limited by the box I am running the code on?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While I'm not sure of the memory footprint, there is a maximum number of rows. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx):

> The maximum number of rows that a DataTable can store is 16,777,216.

Answer (score 7):

According to this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1198310.aspx/1), it is based on your machine...but I like the link because if you are wondering about the limits, you might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum size is limited by Int32. So 2^32 is the maximum number of DataTables you can hold inside a DataSet. So the max size is 2 billion. that is approximately 4GB

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of rows that a DataTable can store is 25,558,144 (visual Studio 2016)