# Storing and transforming rows of data in vb.net - array, list, collection or something else?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, collections

I would like to ask you for advice. I need to extract data from one source (a transportation modelling application that supports vb.net), do some operations on that data and then insert transformed data to the source. 
The source data is a set of rows with two key columns which are integers and third column which is float:

```
StartInterval EndInterval   Weight 
       0          3000      0.504
     3000         8000      0.320
     8000         13500     0.048
    ...............................
    ...............................
```

The number of rows in the source set is known and constant. After saving, this rowset should be transformed using some simple mathematic operations. After that it should be further transformed and expanded so that the number of rows as well as the values of Intervals will grow. At last the rowset will be used to fill again the vb.net object of the application.

Please give me an advice which vb.net objects should I use to reach my goal. I should be able to easily iterate through that object and it should have dynamic size. I don't want to use any Excel sheet as a temporary container of that data, because I would like to use vb code in an internal script of application I'm using.

Can anybody help me ? If it is necessary I can provide more info about my case.

Comment: If you could provide a rough estimate of the amount of data that would be present that would help too

Comment: How I see, `DataTable` can store 16,777,216 rows, but it depend of memory. If You store 1mil rows x 1kB every row it's almost 1gb of ram. I will provide You some links about Your question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11123133/3279496  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e35b9035-456b-4893-8fe3-eff8093fa21c/avoid-memory-issues-while-storing-millions-of-rows-in-c-datatable?forum=winforms

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```css
Imports System.Data
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("StartInterval", GetType(Integer))
        dt.Columns.Add("EndInterval", GetType(Integer))
        dt.Columns.Add("Weight", GetType(Double))

        dt.Rows.Add({0, 3000, 0.504})
        dt.Rows.Add({3000, 8000, 0.32})
        dt.Rows.Add({8000, 13500, 0.048})

    End Sub

End Module
​
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reply

@Saragis

The maximum amount of source data is 35 rows and the maximum amount of transformed data will be ~1800 rows.

@all

I've forgotten there is a DataTable object in vb.net. It seems that's the best way to save this kind of data. I hope it would be possible to iterate through it.